# how to take int or double type input in C# in console?

Tags: c#-4.0, input, console-application

how to take input of int or double type in C# in console???
i had taken input in C++ and C .But in C# ,i am not able to give user input at the run time. So tell how to take input at the run time in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read a line of textual input using `Console.ReadLine()`, then parse it as a number using `int.Parse()` or `double.TryParse()` or other variants.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

double a;
int b;

a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());  // Value in double

b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());   // Value in Int

Answer (score 1):

Use `Console.ReadLine` to read input as string and then convert them to your required type, using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`, or `double.Parse`, or `double.TryParse` like:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

int temp;

if (int.TryParse(input, out temp))
{
    //valid int input
}
else
{
    //invalid int input

}
Console.WriteLine(temp); //input number
```

Its better if you use `TryParse` family of methods for parsing, since they will not raise an exception in case of failed parsing.

You may also see: How to: [Convert a String to a Number (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397679.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use Console.ReadLine() that lets you to put an input and you can assign it to the input you wish, if int then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

ex:

```
Console.Writeline("1. Do Something");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```